# ZeroMQ XREP -- Endpoint disappearing

Tags: zeromq

I am using a standard LRU queue as defined by the ZeroMQ guide [figure 41](http://zguide.zeromq.org/chapter%3aall#toc47), and I am wondering how to add in protection so that I don't send messages to end points that have disappeared (server crash, OOM killer, anything along those lines).

From the documentation I read that XREP will just drop the message if it is going to a non-existant end-point, and there is no way I get notified about that. Is there a way to get such a notification? Should I just send out a "ping" first and if I don't get a response then that "worker" is dead meat to me? How will I know that it is the same client that I just sent the ping to that I am getting the message back from?

Or is my use case not a good one for ZeroMQ? I just want to make sure that a message has been received, I don't want it being dropped on the floor without my knowledge...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pinging a worker to know if it is alive will cause a race condition: the worker might well answer the ping just before it dies.

However, if you assume that a worker will not die **during** a request processing (you can do little in this case), you can reverse the flow of communication between the workers and the central queue. Let the worker fetch a request from the queue (using a `REQ`/`REP` connection) and have it send the answer along with the original envelope when the processing is done (using the same socket as above, or even better through a separate `PUSH`/`PULL` connection).

With this scenario, you know that a dead worker will not be sent requests, as it will be unable to fetch them (being dead…). Moreover, your central queue can even ensure that it receives an answer to every request in a given time. If it does not, it can put the request back in the queue so that a new worker will fetch it shortly after. This way, even if a worker dies while processing a request, the request will eventually be served.

(as a side note: be careful if the worker crashes because of a particular request - you do not want to kill your workers one by one, and might want to put a maximum number of tries for a request)

**Edit:** I wrote [some code](https://github.com/samueltardieu/zmq-broker) implementing [the other direction](http://www.rfc1149.net/blog/2010/12/08/responsible-workers-with-0mq/) to explain what I mean.

Comment: What way would the REP/REQ go? Right now the router I have is XREP -> REQ, should I just change that to XREQ -> REP. Would that still allow me to do LRU load balancing?

Comment: I just edited my answer to add a link to some code + blog post I wrote to answer your question and another one.

Comment: That is genius. I just hadn't though of that, as my worry was this: The REQ socket would send out the request, then die. The router wouldn't know this and would attempt to send to the client, at which point it blocks, which would be bad. After some testing though I saw that the REP will just completely remove the connection even if something was received if the REQ hangs up before the message is recv()'ed by the REP.